# Recurring UIAlertView when no internet

Tags: uialertview, reachability

I've used the reachability code provided by apple and created a UIAlert that displays when the app is first loaded via the applicationDidBecomeActive action of the AppDelegate.m file. This alert works fine, however, after dismissing the alert the user is still able to interact with the UI and in doing so crashes the app because it is not able to gather the necessary data from the internet. I am wondering if there is a way to make my UIAlert repeadtedly pop up after it is dismissed unless internet service becomes available?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your customers & users would probably be very annoyed if they had a non-dismissable or constantly repeating UIAlertView.

I'd recommend displaying the text "I understand" under your alert view's "You need a valid & working Internet connection" message and displaying it only once if the internet goes down and they are trying to do something that requires a remote connection.

But if you insist on having a alert view pop up over and over again, at least give the user some time (e.g. seconds or minutes or *some period*) where they can go to the Network Pane and bring up a WiFi network or enable 3G or whatever.

Comment: I agree that it would be annoying. I was more concerned that the app store might reject the app if the user has the opportunity to cause it to crash, although it seems that it is pretty clear with the initial alert that they should not expect the app to work without internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An recurring alertview would be extremely annoying. If your application can't run without an internet connection, simply prompt your user to switch it on and restart the app. Another way would be adding limited offline functionality and use reachability to wait till an internet connection is available.